# Ideas for adding a second internet connection to existing network?

Tags: routing, load-balancing, dsl, t1

I have a remote site with a T1 connection tied back to a main location.  This provides access to the servers at the main location and also provides internet access via the main location.

The problem is that it is becoming too slow and I want to install a second internet connection.  Most likely it will be a standard DSL (3mb) connection.

The T1 (through an older ADTran router) must remain as-is and continue to act as a bridge between this remote LAN and the main location.

I am looking for ideas on how I might connect this second network connection and allow any non-lan traffic (any non 192.168.x) to go through it.

The ad-tran has a second port I believe, but I think it may be rated at T1 speed only.

There is a 3Com Super Stack all the machines are plugged in to to form the LAN.

If a new hardware device is required, it needs to be very economical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you'd want to load-balance it as much as just send traffic destined for your main location to your main location and traffic meant for the Internet through your DSL line. You could do that by putting a router in front of your gateways that directs the internal traffic to your T1 and all other traffic to the DSL line.

If you're looking for an economical solution you could configure a Linux box as a router and put that in to handle the connections. There are turn-key router boot disks for Linux that will turn even very low-power systems destined for recycling into capable routers.

Comment: Can you give a couple examples for me to check out?  I have used packages such as ClearOS and PfSense, but the issue I have had with those is getting them to be transparent and not impact the functionality of lan bridge.   Possibly what you are suggesting is something much simpler than those packages that does purely routing?

Comment: There's a wiki page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions that lists some. Many distros combine firewall with routing; you just need the routing features, really. Or you can just set up a plain Linux system and configure the forwarding and routing of packets by hand with a routing howto. There's nothing special about the pre-made distros other than adding a web or GUI interface to them to make them easier to use.

Comment: Thanks.   It also just occured to me, I could probably do the same thing by adding a routing entry in the SuperStack to route my LAN destination ip traffic to the AdTran router (T1) and all other traffic to the ip of the DSL router...?

Comment: If it supports it and that's your primary router, sure.